# Data to long for column columname at row1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This text i want to save in mysql table column

> The Institute of Corporate Planning is well reputed institute providing higher
>       education in the field of Management and Computer Science. Presently, the 
>      institute using  manual system for administrative work which resulting in
>      in consistency and time consuming. So to overcome this problem the institute 
>      decided to develop the integration of various departments for office automation, 
>      being You as ERP consultant discuss the pre-implementation and post- implementation
>      key success factors. Also prepare the detail report about the ERP implementation.

I want to store this entire text into one column but it give error.

```
Data too long for column columname at row1.
```

So which data type I can use in mysql to store such long text.

Comment: Post the table definition - then we might be able to give you a clear answer

Comment: @mike i have the column question.i used TEXT,LONGTEXT as datatype to store such large text.but it not working

Comment: Your error message refers to `columname`. Are you working with the right column? Please post the table definition and your code, or we're working in the dark.

Answer (score 4):

You can try TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT or even LONGTEXT.

See that link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/choosing-types.html

Or else: http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html

Comment: it is not working i uses LONGTEXT,MEDIUMTEXT,TEXT but not working.is it posible to store such large string??

Comment: LONGTEXT supports a string with 4GB of data. Do you need more than this?